# Pytorch gpu usage is low

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying the example of pytorch from https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html.
When i run this example, the GPU usage is ~1% and finish time is 130s
While for CPU case, the CPU usage get ~90% and finish time is 79s
My CPU is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700
and my GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070.

I want to ask if it is normal that CPU is running faster than GPU ?
Because the GPU usage is so small (compare with what i see from another website)
Here is the code i run (similar from website).

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

def run():
    # ==================================================================================
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(),
         transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                            download=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                              shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                           download=True, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

    classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
               'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')


    # ==================================================================================
    # # functions to show an image


    # def imshow(img):
    #     img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    #     npimg = img.numpy()
    #     plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))
    #     plt.show()


    # # get some random training images
    # dataiter = iter(trainloader)
    # images, labels = dataiter.next()


    # # show images
    # imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
    # # print labels
    # print(' '.join('%5s' % classes[labels[j]] for j in range(4)))
    # ==================================================================================
    class Net(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Net, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
            self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
            self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
            self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

        def forward(self, x):
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
            x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
            x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
            x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
            x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
            x = self.fc3(x)
            return x
    net = Net()
    device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    print(device)
    net.to(device)
    # ==================================================================================
    import torch.optim as optim

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().to(device)
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
    # ==================================================================================
    for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times

        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data[0].to(device), data[1].to(device)


            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = net(inputs).to(device)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels).to(device)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0

    print('Finished Training')
    # ==================================================================================
    PATH = './cifar_net.pth'
    torch.save(net.state_dict(), PATH)

    # ==================================================================================
    # ==================================================================================
    # ==================================================================================


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: I'm not a pytorch expert but I have noticed when training AI models in other libraries it is CUDA usage that goes up, not 3D render usage which most GPU monitors display.

Comment: You're probably seeing the increased initialization time. When using cuda tensors the first iteration of the training loop spends quite a while transferring model information to the GPU. If you time each iteration of the loop after the first (use `torch.cuda.synchronize()` at the end of the loop body while timing GPU code) then you'll probably find that after the first iteration the cuda version is much faster. If you increase the number of layers and channels in your network then this will probably become even more apparent.

Comment: You're using a batch size of 4 and a model that is very small, there are not many GPU calculations happening there. Have you tried with a higher batch size (for example 200 or more) or using a more complex model? There will always be an overhead to transfer data from CPU to GPU, you need to reach a certain number of uninterrupted calculations on the GPU for it to be faster.

Comment: Agree with Michael (may be post as an answer ? ), you also may try to move your data to SSD drive it will reduce time to load batches and will increase % of GPU time in cycle.

Comment: @MichaelJungo Oh my GOD, I was searching for hours trying to figure out why it was going so slowly. THANK YOU, turns out all I needed was to up my batch size. I wish pytorch made that more clear.

Comment: @MichaelJungo as Andrey suggested, this is a valid solution to OP problem. Please consider revising the comment and post it as an answer. Thank you 