# Algorithm doesn’t run on GPU even after storing model and data into GPU. What am i missing?

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, conv-neural-network

You can find training section of my code below:

```
device = torch.device(‘cuda’ if torch.cuda.is_available() else ‘cpu’)
```

Note: I am receiving True when i check torch.cuda.is_available

After creating CNN model i wrote:

```
model = model.to(device)
```

Training Section:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

epochs = 3

#Limits on numbers of batches if you want train faster(Not mandatory)
max_trn_batch = 800 # batch 10 image --> 8000 images total
max_tst_batch = 300 # batch 10 image --> 3000 images total

train_losses = []
test_losses = []
train_correct = []
test_correct = []

for i in range(epochs):

trn_corr = 0
tst_corr = 0

for b,(X_train,y_train) in enumerate(train_loader):
    X_train,y_train = X_train.to(device),y_train.to(device)
    
    #optinal limit number of batches
    if b == max_trn_batch:
        break
    b = b + 1
    
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    loss = criterion(y_pred,y_train)
    
    predicted = torch.max(y_pred.data,1)[1]
    batch_corr = (predicted == y_train).sum()
    trn_corr = trn_corr + batch_corr
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    if b%200 == 0:
        print('Epoch:  {} Loss:  {} Accuracy:  {}'.format(i,loss,trn_corr.item()*100/(10*b)))

train_losses.append(loss)
train_correct.append(trn_corr)


#test set

with torch.no_grad():
    for b,(X_test,y_test) in enumerate(test_loader):
        X_test,y_test = X_test.to(device),y_test.to(device)
        
        #Optional
        if b==max_tst_batch:
            break
        y_val = model(X_test)
        predicted = torch.max(y_val.data,1)[1]
        batch_corr = (predicted == y_test).sum()
        tst_corr = tst_corr + batch_corr

loss = criterion(y_val,y_test)
test_losses.append(loss)
test_correct.append(tst_corr)
total_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f’Total Time: {total_time/60}) minutes’)
```

And during the training i am checking the CPU and GPU performance , CPU working %100 while GPU %1.

Note: Algorithm took 13 minutes when i use CPU as device, and took 7 min when i used GPU as device, so there seems tiny improvement, but i couldnt see any gpu utilization on task manager during training.

Note2:Parameters

```
ConvolutionalNetwork(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1))
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=46656, out_features=120, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=120, out_features=84, bias=True)
  (fc3): Linear(in_features=84, out_features=2, bias=True)
```

)

Comment: maybe the task manager does not show GPU usage well. i've also had trouble monitoring it sometimes.

Comment: Maybe, but i really wonder isnt that improvement from 13 min to 7 min is really low for using gpu instead of  cpu? Thats why i am aimed to believe i am not using gpu properly as task manager shows.

Comment: Fair enough. Maybe the task is so that it does not get to utilize it fully, like maybe it has to wait for data to arrive. Almost 50% improvement is quite a lot though.

Comment: I understand what you mean, just i would like to give you further information just to be sure. This is my full code [link]https://github.com/euguroglu/Machine-Learning-Projects/blob/master/Cuda_Pytorch_CNN_Chest_X_ray_classification.ipynb

Comment: And i used nvidia-smi to check utilization and it was %1, which seems quite low. Isnt it? While CPU utilization is %100.

Comment: True - though I don't think you get from 13mins on CPU to 7 mins on GPU if it'd actually only use 1%. Am still doubtful about the GPU usage reporting. I found some hints, maybe your batch size is so small that GPU mostly sits waiting? Is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707665/pytorch-gpu-usage-is-low . . This seemed relevant too, https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-make-sure-that-pytorch-using-gpu-to-compute/4870/14 .. links to https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/cuda.html

Comment: I increased batch size from 10 to 1000 and carefully observed GPU utilization and it is increased from %1 to % 5 for every 20 sec. So i think you were right(thanks a lot), it was about to size of the batch, btw total process time is still 6.9 minutes, i expected it could be reduced i little bit since there is less gpu in and gpu out process compared to previous one.